# The originator of the fixed point theorem for DCPOs

Tags: reference-request, partial-order, fixed-points

Pataraia proved in

> "A constructive proof of Tarski’s fixed-point theorem for dcpo's", presented in the 65th Peripatetic Seminar on Sheaves and Logic, in Aarhus, Denmark, November 1997

that in a directed-complete partial order (dcpo) with a minimum element each monotone map has a fixpoint. (For the purpose of this particular theorem, a directed set is a poset in which each finite subset is bounded from above, and a dcpo is a poset in which each directed subset has a supremum.) Dito Pataraia is mostly acknowledged for the new proof method rather than the theorem itself.

Who was the first to actually state and prove this theorem is *any* way? One can argue that the proof of Markowski's Theorem 9(i) in "[Chain-complete posets and directed sets with applications](http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/Markowsky1976_30.pdf)" can be adapted to our situation. Still, the clear-cut statement of the aforementioned theorem is not present in Markowski's paper.

Answer (score 4):

The non-constructive version of Pataraia's theorem is called the Bourbaki-Witt fixed point theorem. I learned it from Davey and Priestley's *Introduction to Lattices and Order*, and Wikipedia gives the following references:

- Nicolas Bourbaki (1949). "Sur le théorème de Zorn". Archiv der Mathematik. 2: 434–437. [doi:10.1007/bf02036949](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02036949).
- Ernst Witt (1951). "Beweisstudien zum Satz von M. Zorn". Mathematische Nachrichten. 4: 434–438. [doi:10.1002/mana.3210040138](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.3210040138).

However, as usual, some classically equivalent formulations of this theorem become distinguishable constructively. Andrej Bauer and Peter Lumsdaine have a very nice paper about this, [*On the Bourbaki-Witt Principle in Toposes*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0340), where they examine these issues in detail.

Comment: @user49915: I guess I don't understand your question, then. My understanding was that (a) the Bourbaki-Witt theorem is that every inflationary function on a chain-complete poset has a least fixed point, (b) Pataraia's theorem is that monotone functions on pointed domains have least fixed points, and (c) Markowsky's Theorem is that chain-complete posets and dcpos are the same thing. So (c) implies (a) and (b) are equivalent. (Also, I must admit I never read any of these papers (except the Bauer-Lumsdaine one): I learned the theorems second-hand...)

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, note that if you have a DCPO D and a monotone function f, you can define the set of post-fixed-points $\{ x \in D